# Hide Element When Parent Element is Hovered/Active/Focus on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay I am trying to hide the h6 on hover/active/focus for the div class="item" and only the current one (as there are multiple divs with item class) - then when they are not redisplay it.  The h6 is a caption on the image and the figcaption comes in as a rollover caption.  So the two are competing and wouldn't be an issue if the figcaption rollover was at 100% opacity, but it is not. For this example css :hover and z-index will not work.  This seems simple, but I keep tripping up on it and hide the h6 on any item hover.

```
        <div class="item w1 h1"><h6>Test</h6>
        <figure><img src="img/test.jpg" alt="Test" />
            <figcaption>
                <p>Test Test</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>

   <div class="item w1 h1"><h6>Test 2</h6>
        <figure><img src="img/test2.jpg" alt="Test2" />
            <figcaption>
                <p>Test2 Test2</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

I've used many variations of this jQuery...

```
$('.item h6').hover(function(event){$(this).css({display: 'none'});
$(".item").hover(function(){$("h6").css({display: "none"});});
```

etc...

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript/jQuery you tried.

Comment: @j08691 Add the jQuery in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use pure css, much cleaner and easier:

```
.item:hover > h6 {display:none;}
```

Comment: What the H-ll  LOL - I had it as .item >h6:hover.  Thanks a ton!